# Upgrade from Sitecore 9.0 initial version to Sitecore 9 update 2

Tags: migration, express-migration-tool, content-migration

We're working on the Sitecore upgrade from Sitecore 7.2 to Sitecore 9 update2. Using the express migration tool, we moved all the content from sitecore7.2 to sitecore 9 initial version and updated the references and breaking changes and it almost works fine.

To move from Sitecore 9 initial version to Sitecore 9 update 2, There are some upgrade scripts which are available.

Note: Current project is not using any DMS functionalities and sitecore customization is very less.

I have a couple of questions.

1. Shall i take the packages from sitecore 9 initial version and
   install the package to sitecore 9 update2 directly since i don't
   have much sitecore customizations and No XDb migrations?
2. When do we follow upgrade option? ( i mean upgrading from sitecore 9
   Initial version to Sitecore 9 update2 using Upgrade scripts and
   Upgrade packages)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already on Sitecore 9.0 Initial Update, I don't think you need to create packages and install on Update 2. And obviously since Express Migration Tool 3.1 doesn't support any targeted version greater than 9.0 Initial Version, you can't use that. I would rather Upgrade the same SC 9.0 Initial Version instance to Update 2.

From this stage onward I will follow the step below:

Backup everything, especially database. Preferable use any source control and check-in the current state. Follow the Upgrade Guide provided with SC9 Update 2:

1. Preparing to Upgrade from Sitecore XP 9.0

   - Disable Experience Analytics.
   - Stop Two Windows Services - Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer service and Sitecore 
     Marketing Automation Engine service.
   - Disable the Data Migration Too.
   - Upgrade the Databases.
2. Final Preparations for Upgrading from All Versions

   - STOP all the content test.
   - Disable the Web Forms for Marketers Module – If Installed.
   - Enable Email Experience Manager – MOST IMPORTANT, cause on SC9 Update 2 EXM will be 
     part of the platform.
3. Then follow the steps provided under - *Upgrade from Sitecore XP 9.0 Initial Release*  and beyond.